# magento createBlock with variable identifier that depend on chosen language

Tags: magento

I have a magento template with 3 store views (gb,de,dk) and with static block set in CMS Admin with identifier contact_us_gb displayed in the frontend header. In the content of the static block I just have an HTML code for image contact_us_gb.gif

In the header.phtml it is set by the following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact_us_gb')->toHtml() ?>
```

Since I have 3 different languages, I created 2 more static blocks in CMS Admin with identifiers contact_us_dk and contact_us_de with their corresponding contents containing HTML code for images contact_us_dk.gif and contact_us_de.gif

how can I have a variable name in the setBlockId('contact_us') so that the correct block identifier is selected when the customer changes the store language?

In short, if customer chooses danish language, the **identifier** in `setBlockID('identifier')` changes to 'contact_us_dk'. 
If customer chooses german language, the **identifier** in `setBlockID('identifier')` changes to 'contact_us_de'.

Comment: You'll probably do better asking this on [magento.se]

Comment: but magento requires different identifiers for the static blocks. How can I have the same name 'contact' for each static block?

Comment: It seems I have managed to solve the problem by adding the following code before calling createBlock
 $storeCode=Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); 
then in the createBlock('identifier') I substituted 'identifier' with 'contact_us_'.$storeCode
It works now!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the answer to your question, but it's a solution to your problem.
Create 3 static blocks, one for each language (enable them just in one store each), and name them the same `contact`.
Them you can add this line in your template

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('contact')->toHtml() ?>
```

and not care about the language you are in.